# Reproduce result from matlab's gradient function in python

Tags: python, matlab

The following matlab code:

```
gradient([2, 4, 7, 11, 18], [100000, 90000, 80000, 70000, 60000])
```

returns:

```
-0.0002  -0.00025  -0.00035  -0.00055  -0.0007
```

I would like python to do the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```py
import numpy as np

a = [2, 4, 7, 11, 18]
b = [100000, 90000, 80000, 70000, 60000]

g = np.gradient(a, b)
```

Comment: note that I was on numpy v1.12.1, and had to upgrade to v1.13.3 for this to work.