# Reproducing Multidimensional Gradient Results in Python

Tags: python, numpy, octave

In Octave, I have

```matlab
x = -0.8:0.2:1;
y = -0.8:0.2:1;
z = -0.8:0.8:1;

[xx,yy,zz] = meshgrid(x, y, z);

u = sin(pi .* xx) .* cos(pi .* yy) .* cos(pi .* zz);

dx = xx(1,:,1)(:);
dy = yy(:,1,1)(:);
dz = zz(1,1,:)(:);

[a, b, c] = gradient (u, dx, dy, dz);
b(1,:,1)
```

which outputs

```matlab
1.18882   1.92355   1.92355   1.18882   0.00000  -1.18882  -1.92355  -1.92355  -1.18882  -0.00000
```

With Python, I tried to replicate it,

```py
import numpy as np

xx, yy, zz = np.meshgrid(np.arange(-0.8, 1.2, 0.2),
                         np.arange(-0.8, 1.2, 0.2),
                         np.arange(-0.8, 1.2, 0.8))


u = np.sin(np.pi * xx) * np.cos(np.pi * yy) * np.cos(np.pi * zz)

dx = xx[0,:,0]
dy = yy[:,0,0]
dz = zz[0,0,:]

a,b,c = np.gradient (u, dx, dy, dz)
print (b[0,:,0])
```

I get

```py
[-1.18882065 -0.59441032  0.59441032  1.55618643  1.92355221  1.55618643
  0.59441032 -0.59441032 -1.55618643 -1.92355221]
```

which looks different. How do I get the Numpy `gradient` call match the Octave results?

My Numpy version is 1.19.0, Octave is 4.2.2.

I saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47882492/reproduce-result-from-matlabs-gradient-function-in-python/47882531) asking another Matlab / Python gradient question, that call works for me, which I guess is the low dimensional case.

Comment: Please read the tag descriptions of [tag:octave] and [tag:matlab]. They are explicitly **not** the same. Only use both tags if you are asking about differences or similarities between the two. If you only use Octave, don't tag-spam [tag:matlab] along for the clicks please, as you'd force people to adapt their answers so that they work in both languages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Matlab/Octave use column major layout by default
- Numpy use row major layout by default

So you need to inverse the axis order of the first two dimensions:

```
a,b,c = np.gradient (u, dx, dy, dz, axis=[1,0,2])
```