# np.gradient and matlab gradient

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, gradient

I am trying to reproduce the matlab gradient function result in python using the numpy.gradient one but what I get is very different from the result proposed by Matlab.

Unfortunately I don’t have anymore a working Matlab installed, so I cannot check it in details.

Given 3 numbers (increments along the three directions):

```
dx=1e-7
dy=1e-7
dz=1e-3,
```

My matlab code was:

```
[F1, F2, F3] = gradient(F, dx,dy,dz)
```

What is the equivalent expression in python?

I used:

```
F1, F2, F3 = np.gradient(F, dx, dy, dz)
```

But the graph I get is far from being comparable.

Comment: Do [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64006199/reproducing-multidimensional-gradient-results-in-python/64007354#64007354) solve your problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming F is a 2D matrix, the `[FX,FY] = gradient(F)` function of Matlab gives the same results as `[FY,FX]=numpy.gradient(F, edge_order=1)`.

Answer (score -1):

Per [Numpy documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.gradient.html), `numpy.gradient()` computes the numerical gradient using central differences for the interior points and lets you choose the accuracy at the boundaries using the `edge_order` option:

`numpy.gradient(f, *varargs, axis=None, edge_order=1)`

Matlab uses central differences, which is accurate up to 2nd order, so if you set `edge_order = 2`, you should get the same as Matlab's output.

`[F1, F2, F3] = np.gradient(F, dx, dy, dz, edge_order=2)`

Comment: From [the MATLAB docs](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/gradient.html#bvifdfu-5): “`gradient` calculates values along the edges of the matrix with single-sided differences.”